# Is there a way to flip a label in kivy horizontally?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

So that it's like when you look at it from a mirror. Can't just do `texture_size(-100,50)` for example, will stay straight

Answer (score 0):

A semi hacky way to do this is to flip it vertically then rotate the image to have the same effect that flipping horizontally would

python file:

```
class MirrorCamera(Camera):
    def _camera_loaded(self, *largs):
        self.texture = self._camera.texture            
        self.texture_size = list(self.texture.size)
        self.texture.flip_vertical()
```

kivy file:

```
<MirrorCamera>
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Translate:
            xy: (self.x + self.width / 2, self.y + self.height / 2)
        Rotate:
            angle: 180
            axis: (0, 0, 1.0)
        Translate:
            xy: (-self.x - self.width / 2, -self.y - self.height / 2)
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
```

Comment: That is SO weird. So it's like making it 3d first, then looking it from a camera?